# WKWebView: localStorage becomes null on window.close

Tags: wkwebview

I have some 3rd-party content in a WKWebView that tries to read from localStorage on window-close. WKWebView doesn't trigger any events on window.close, so I'm doing it myself in the `webViewDidClose` delegate method.

The problem is that as soon as `window.close()` is executed, localStorage becomes null! This does not happen in a desktop browser window. Interestingly, only localStorage is lost, sessionStorage remains accessible.

In Safari inspector console:

```
onunload=function() {
    debugger;
    // localStorage is null
    // sessionStorage is Storage
}
close();
```

On the native side:

```
func webViewDidClose(_ webView: WKWebView) {
    // Trigger the unload event before closing the web view
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("dispatchEvent(new Event('unload'));")

    // Give the content some time to respond to the event, and then destroy the web view
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) {
        self.webView?.removeFromSuperview();
        self.webView = nil
    }
}
```